# Best way to transfer bulk data

Tags: java, asp.net-web-api, protocol-buffers, data-transfer

I have 2 requirements, both involving data-transfer. 
In the first one I have an application 'A' which has data in its staging table of database, this data has to be transferred to another application 'B'. Here there are around 50k-60k records that need to be transferred daily. I want to know what is the best way to transfer this? should i still follow the old school method of creating a file and transferring it or go for web-API's or anything else? Please suggest anything in JAVA.

In the second one, i have a file that needs to be transferred from app 'A' to app 'B'. The file size is of around 10GB. what is the best way of achieving it? I had a look at IBM ESB, is there any other better alternate?

Comment: Hi, Can anyone help me understand if i can go with protocol buffers?

Answer (score 0):

This is best done outside of any API because it will likely take quite a bit of time.

My suggestion is to export the data to csv, zip it up, transfer it to the other system via ftp for example.

On the second system you would need something which monitors the folder where you ftp stuff and this other thing would take care of getting the data into the second system. I have setup such a system using the Azure cloud for example using Webjobs and it worked very well.

You can also come up with something else which is appropriate to your specific case.

Comment: will google's protocol buffer too not solve the problem through API's?